# GDB with qemu doesnt stop at breakpoints

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, kernel, bootloader

I'm trying to debug my kernel with gdb but it wont stop at breakpoints for some reason

compile kernel:

```
    gcc -g -Werror -nostdlib -o kernel.o -c kernel/main.c
    gcc -g -nostdlib -ffreestanding -e kmain -o kernel.elf kernel.o
```

kernel/main.c

```
int kmain(Bootinfo *Bootinfo) {
    
    for (;;);
}
```

and this is how i call into it from the bootloader

```
    stat = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->ExitBootServices, 2, IH, mapkey);
    kmain(&bootinfo);
```

qemu

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd -drive file=/os.img,format=raw
```

and gdb

```
target remote :1234
symbol-file kernel.elf
break kmain
continue
layout next
```

even after `break kmain` it says Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000: file kernel/main.c, line 5
But after `continue` it just doesnt stop

Comment: Two suggestions that sometimes help: compile with `-Og` to optimize for debugging, and separate the `for` loop into two lines, so you can breakpoint on the `;` loop body.

Comment: @sj95126 ok now it works, btw should the `-Og` be used when linking or compiling? Or during both?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain that optimization flags don't affect the linking stage in any way, but if it doesn't give an error, it doesn't hurt to use it.

Comment: AFAIK, doing `break kmain` breaks on the function prolog. But, it doesn't put a break on the `for` loop. So, the behavior is correct. I'd add a function (in a separate `.c` file): `void gdbstop(void) { }` [to prevent the compiler from "inspecting" it and eliding the call to it]. Then, `for (;;) gdbstop();` in `main`. You can do: `break gdbstop`

Comment: @sj95126 I have a new problem, with `-Og` enabled IF i add a new function to the kernel file, it will not stop at `kmain`?

Comment: Any time you make changes and have weird behavior, it can't hurt to try a clean rebuild, so everything is recompiled and relinked. If that doesn't help, you may need to open a new question.

Comment: @sj95126 i opened a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175466/gdb-is-not-stopping-at-breakpoint-when-debugging-a-pie-kernel

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean up a little, there are two answers for this question:

Disabling KASLR with the `nokaslr` boot argument as suggested here: [debugging kernel with qemu and gdb, breakpoint not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844209/debugging-kernel-with-qemu-and-gdb-breakpoint-not-working)

Or your own follow up question [GDB is not stopping at breakpoint when debugging a PIE kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73175466/gdb-is-not-stopping-at-breakpoint-when-debugging-a-pie-kernel) : Use `file <name> -o <offset>` to match the memory relocation in QEMU.