# GDB is not stopping at breakpoint when debugging a PIE kernel

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gcc, gdb

I have a position independent kernel that gets compiled and linked like this:

```
    gcc -Og -g -Werror -nostdlib -o kernel.o -c kernel/main.c
    gcc -nostdlib -ffreestanding -e kmain -o kernel.elf kernel.o
```

The problem I have is that when I launch the bootloader in qemu like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd -drive file=/os.img,format=raw
```

and then do this in gdb:

```
target remote :1234                                                             
symbol-file kernel.elf                                               
break kmain                                                             
continue                                                                        
layout next
```

it will not stop at the breakpoint, it just keeps continuing.

This is how I call kmain from the bootloader:

```
    int (*kmain)(void*) = (int(*)(void*)) (buf + elf->entry);
    stat = uefi_call_wrapper(BS->ExitBootServices, 2, IH, mapkey);
    kmain(&bootinfo);
```

where `buf` is the beginning of the kernel.elf file and this is the kmain()

```
int kmain(Bootinfo *Bootinfo) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = x;
    return 0;
}
```

Someone told me this:

"If your kernel is position-independent or relocatable and your bootloader can handle the runtime requirements of position-independent or relocatable code, you need to tell GDB that you've loaded your kernel at a different base address."

How can I tell gdb that my kernel is loaded at a different base address?
Is the base address in this case `buf`?

if I disassemble kmain in gdb this is what it shows:
[gdb kmain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjHdd.png)

Comment: Why do  you think you have a pie kernel? You don't specify -fpic, -fpie, etc when compiling? Can you breakpoint on the bootloader? To be able to have a bootloader interpret an ELF format binary, there must be a bit of code. How do you know you even get to the invocation lines? What ability do you have to do `printf` from the bootloader? For kernels, `printf` debug can sometimes be far more valuable that `gdb`

Answer (score 1):

in gdb the command `symbol-file` can be given a `-o offset` argument:

`symbol-file [ filename [ -o offset ]]`

> If an optional offset is specified, it is added to the start address of each section in the symbol file. This is useful if the program is relocated at runtime, such as the Linux kernel with kASLR enabled.

source: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html